# Messages in Mqtt Android

Tags: android, mqtt

I have a scenario in which Sender send a message on a topic. But there is a client which was never connected previously at all, connect and subscribe to same topic. How can he receive all the messages previously present on that topic for newly connected client.

I used cleanSession = false nothing happens

I used the Retained message = true. Then only last message is recieved.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't.

The broker will only queue messages for clients that already have sessions (have logged on at least once with cleanSession=false).

Retained messages only keep the last message sent to that topic.

If you want historical messages like you describe then you will need to store them in a database and request them via some other mechanism (e.g. http)

Answer (score 0):

The broker store the last retained message and the corresponding QoS for that topic. Each client that subscribes to a topic pattern, which matches the topic of the retained message, will receive the message immediately after subscribing.

For each topic only one retained message will be stored by the broker.So you can't get all the retained messages